# reset counter in while loop bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm struggling with this script, I have tried different thing but I can't get it to work.

I tried with if ,doesn't work, I tried with nested while also without success. I don't know what to do any more...

If the value imax has reached 10 i want it to start over with 1

this is the code:

```
folder="f"
ps=20000
name="test"
i=1
imax=1

while [ $i -le 20 ]
    do
        cd
        cd "$folder$((i))"
        sed -i 1s/.*/$name$((imax))/ file.txt
        sed -i 2s/.*/$ps/ file.txt
        (( i++ ))
        (( imax++ ))
    done
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this works:

```
i=1
imax=1
while [ $i -le 20 ]   
   do
       echo $i $imax
       (( i++ ))
       (( imax++ ))
       if [ $imax -eq 10 ]; then  imax=1; fi
   done
```